# Slow SELECT statement, possibly due to WHERE?

Tags: sql, time-series, questdb

Database has a few million rows.

This is meant to find products priced above the average price:

```sql
SELECT ProductName, Price 
FROM Products
WHERE Price > (SELECT AVG(Price) FROM Products);
```

However, it's pretty slow.

I think this is because it recalculates the average for every row.

Is there a way to optimize this query?

I tried a few different types of queries, though I think I'm missing something.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Do you have any indices on table `Products`?

Comment: Couldn't you verify your hypothesis by executing the inner select first, see how long it takes, then plug in the result in the outer select and execute that one? If it really makes a difference you could try WITH to create a table with the average and then use that one in the query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HAVING:

```
SELECT ProductName, MAX(Price) AS Price
FROM Products 
GROUP BY ProductName
HAVING (SELECT AVG(Price) FROM Products) < Price;
```

Comment: Incorrect syntax, please try out queries before creating an answer. See https://dbfiddle.uk/ZvWRRYQ9. And why do you think using an additional `GROUP BY` will improve the performance? Please explain your idea rather than just write down a query.

Comment: Thanks for the observation.
I copied manually from my sql editor and made a typo in the Select.
We use "group by" so we can use "having", and we use "having" because "having" is calculated for the data set, while "where" is calculated for each row.
The only problem that this statement could have is if there were more than one product with the same name, but the "group by" could be done with the primary key of the table, for example.

Comment: I have test it in MySQL and MariaDB.